# logical drive as dvd drive

Tags: dvd, hard-drive

I am having a English learning DVD, i copy complete dvd into my hard disk then install that english learning software from hard disk, after i install i try to run the installed software it said your dvd is not into Dvd rom please insert dvd and they start play it.

Comment: I think this question belongs to superuser.com rather than here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"magic Disk" is the one to create virtual drive, works for me chilll